# How to make full search work in 2010/2013 outlook exchange with cache off?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, cache

Windows 10
With Outlook 2010
With Outlook 2013

Tried on two machines, and got same results with different users.

Our search bar in exchange is not working( only getting the last few days), especially when cache mode is off. When the cache mode is on it gets all emails from beginning of time.  Tried both methods in 2010/ and 2013 outlook exchange.  How to configure it to make it that it finds all emails while c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue happens when Outlook is in online mode, please try to [rebuild the index of the mailbox database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633475(v=exchg.150).aspx) the affected users' mailbox resided on.

You may also check if search works in OWA.

Comment: Search Doesn't work well in OWA, and Reindexing has been done. Also a rebuild.

Comment: What's the version of your Exchange server? Have you checked the Database Status by running Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus to check the index healthy. Have a look at this KB:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123701(v=exchg.150).aspx